# Sine wave PWM Arduino Micro

Tags: pwm, wave

I'm trying to generate a sine wave on my Arduino micro. 
I used this code.

```
int Pin = 9;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(Pin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
 float something = millis()/10000.0;
 int value = 128.0 + 128 * sin( something * 2.0 * PI  );
 analogWrite(Pin,value);
}
```

I have a low pass filter at the output of the pin to smooth the wave. The problem is : I get a nice square wave with a duty cycle from 0 to 100%, but not a sine wave. Ideally, I'd like to set a frequency of 10 Hz.
Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake ? Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Maybe a bit of a delay? You will be changing the duty cycle very rapidly.

Comment: I tried it, the duty cycle of the square wave is changing according to the delay, but it's still not a sine wave.

Comment: then your low pass filter isn't enough

Comment: You can make a simple R-2R ladder DAC to create a sin wave. However it does require the use of many I/O pins, depending on the resolution you want in your sin wave.

Answer (score 1):

it is how PWM works. digital pins can do only 1 and 0.

Comment: So it's not possible to do a sine wave?

Comment: Maybe use the PWM to charge a capacitor? You can balance charge and discharge with resistors to possibly get a pretty sinusoidal voltage on it.

Comment: I found you a tutorial that should help you to create a circuit that changes a square wave to sinusoidal wave. All you need to do is to output from your arduino 0 for 50ms and 1 for 50ms (to get 10Hz) and adjust the capacitor sizes to get a sin wave. (Tutorial shows circuit working for 10kHz square wave)
http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Square-to-sine-wave-converter-circuit.php

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake ?

put a lpf on the pwm output.